# im trying to run app after installing requirement.txt from?

Tags: python, web, tensorflow, flask, websocket

I'm trying to run app after installing `requirement.txt` from : https://github.com/victordibia/skyfall

I am getting the following error:

```
File "app.py", line 19, in `<module>`

from utils import web_socket_client

File "C:\Users\anurag\Downloads\skyfall-master\utils\web_socket_client.py", line 8, in <module>

from websocket import WebSocketException, WebSocketConnectionClosedException ImportError: cannot import name 'WebSocketException'`
```

Is there another way of running the app..if needed make changes in the file and send the github link

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have no problems running the app on Debian Linux and Python 3.6.5. Perhaps you need to run it in the python virtual environment to make sure some installed package does not interfere. Instruction for Linux:

1. Clone the git to the local folder:

`git clone https://github.com/victordibia/skyfall`

2. Create python3 virtual environment in the folder nearby:

Install `python3-venv` package using package manager. Run:

`python3 -m venv skyfall_venv`

then
`source skyfall_venv/bin/activate`

Now you are inside the virtual environment, which is indicated in your shell. Do

`(skyfall_venv): pip install --upgrade pip`

if it does not work, do

`(skyfall_venv): pip3 install --upgrade pip`

to have the latest pip in your venv.

3.Then edit `skyfall/requirements.txt` removing extra `-e` in front of git, it must look like the follownig:

```
Flask==0.12.2
opencv_python==3.4.0.12
numpy==1.14.2
tensorflow==1.7.0
protobuf==3.5.2.post1
websocket_client==0.47.0
git+https://github.com/dpallot/simple-websocket-server.git
```

Run inside venv:

`(skyfall_venv): pip install -r requirements.txt` (or `pip3` if the former does not work)

4.You should see no errors. The run the app in venv:

`(skyfall_venv): cd skyfall`

`(skyfall_venv): python app.py`  (or python3 if the former does not work)

I see the window with gesture recognition, and if I open web address in browser which the app suggests, I can play the game.

`cvcam.py`:

```
import cv2

cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)

# Check if the webcam is opened correctly
if not cap.isOpened():
    raise IOError("Cannot open webcam")

while True:
    ret, frame = cap.read()
    frame = cv2.resize(frame, None, fx=0.5, fy=0.5, interpolation=cv2.INTER_AREA)
    cv2.imshow('Input', frame)

    c = cv2.waitKey(1)
    if c == 27:
        break

cap.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```